# Sharing a ClassLoader with Drools 5.6.0 to allow the in-memory compilation of classes at runtime

Tags: classloader, drools, java-compiler-api

I'm writing a simple utility which reads XML files, converts their nodes into POJOs, loads them into a Drools' WM and finally applies some rules to them. You can find the whole project on my [GitHub profile](https://github.com/stefano-bragaglia/Skimmer). Unfortunately, despite all my efforts, I couldn't make Drools to "like" any instance of classes that were compiled at runtime. I saw many people also having problems with the ClassLoader so I suspect it might be its fault... I prepared a *Minimal Working Example* for you to try which is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/stefano-bragaglia/Skimmer) and here below. It requires a few other small files (`MemoryFileManager`, `MemoryJavaClassObject` and `MemoryJavaFileObject`) which are only available on [GitHub](https://github.com/stefano-bragaglia/Skimmer) for brevity. In order to work properly, this example requires that your JVM is a JDK >= 6, and that you have `tools.jar` or `classes.jar` on your `classpath`. The example is the following:

```
public class Example {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Setting the strings that we are going to use...
        String name = "Person";
        String content = "public class " + name + " {\n";
        content += "    private String name;\n";
        content += "    public Person() {\n";
        content += "    }\n";
        content += "    public Person(String name) {\n";
        content += "        this.name = name;\n";
        content += "    }\n";
        content += "    public String getName() {\n";
        content += "        return name;\n";
        content += "    }\n";
        content += "    public void setName(String name) {\n";
        content += "        this.name = name;\n";
        content += "    }\n";
        content += "    @Override\n";
        content += "    public String toString() {\n";
        content += "        return \"Hello, \" + name + \"!\";\n";
        content += "    }\n";
        content += "}\n";
        String value = "HAL";
        String rules = "rule \"Alive\"\n";
        rules += "when\n";
        rules += "then\n";
        rules += "    System.out.println(\"I'm alive!\")\n";
        rules += "end\n";
        rules += "\n";
        rules += "rule \"Print\"\n";
        rules += "when\n";
        rules += "    $o: Object()\n";
        rules += "then\n";
        rules += "    System.out.println(\"DRL> \" + $o.toString())\n";
        rules += "end\n";

        // Compiling the given class in memory
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        JavaFileManager manager = new MemoryFileManager(compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null));
        ClassLoader classLoader = manager.getClassLoader(null);
        List<JavaFileObject> files = new ArrayList<JavaFileObject>();
        files.add(new MemoryJavaFileObject(name, content));
        compiler.getTask(null, manager, null, null, null, files).call();

        try {
            // Instantiate and set the new class
            Class<?> person = classLoader.loadClass(name);
            Method method = person.getMethod("setName", String.class);
            Object instance = person.newInstance();
            method.invoke(instance, value);
            System.out.println(instance);
            System.out.println("We get a salutation, so Person is now a compiled class in memory loaded by the given ClassLoader.");

            // Use the same instance in Drools (by means of the shared ClassLoader)
            KnowledgeBuilderConfiguration config1 = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilderConfiguration(null, classLoader);
            KnowledgeBuilder builder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(config1);
            builder.add(ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(rules.getBytes()), ResourceType.DRL);
            if (builder.hasErrors()) {
                for (KnowledgeBuilderError error : builder.getErrors())
                    System.out.println(error.toString());
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            KnowledgeBaseConfiguration config2 = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBaseConfiguration(null, classLoader);
            KnowledgeBase base = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase(config2);
            base.addKnowledgePackages(builder.getKnowledgePackages());
            StatefulKnowledgeSession session = base.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
            session.insert(instance);
            session.fireAllRules();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Class not found!");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.println("Illegal access!");
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            System.out.println("Instantiation!");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            System.out.println("No such method!");
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            System.out.println("Invocation target!");
        }
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }

}
```

If I run the example, I get the following output:

```
Hello, HAL!
We get a salutation, so Person is now a compiled class in memory loaded by the given ClassLoader.
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Object (wrong name: Person)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at bragaglia.skimmer.core.MemoryFileManager$1.findClass(MemoryFileManager.java:33)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader$CachingLoader.load(CompositeClassLoader.java:258)
    at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader$CachingLoader.load(CompositeClassLoader.java:237)
    at org.drools.util.CompositeClassLoader.loadClass(CompositeClassLoader.java:88)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.drools.base.ClassTypeResolver.resolveType(ClassTypeResolver.java:155)
    at org.drools.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.build(PatternBuilder.java:174)
    at org.drools.rule.builder.PatternBuilder.build(PatternBuilder.java:135)
    at org.drools.rule.builder.GroupElementBuilder.build(GroupElementBuilder.java:67)
    at org.drools.rule.builder.RuleBuilder.build(RuleBuilder.java:85)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addRule(PackageBuilder.java:3230)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileRules(PackageBuilder.java:1038)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.compileAllRules(PackageBuilder.java:946)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(PackageBuilder.java:938)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:470)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:698)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:51)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:40)
    at bragaglia.skimmer.core.Example.main(Example.java:91)
```

As you can see, the `Person` class is successfully compiled in memory and instantiated (see the message `Hello, HAL!` in the output), however if I add it to a WM I get an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Object (wrong name: Person)` even if no rule explicitly relies on `Person`s. Now, I investigated the exception a little bit and I realised that it gets fired when the given class (`Person`) is not found within the `ClassLoader` used by Drools. Therefore I changed my code by adding a configuration with a reference to the very same `ClassLoader` used to compile and instantiate `HAL` to both the `KnowledgeBuilder` and the `KnowledgeBase`, however I might be doing something wrong because I still get the same exception.

Do you have any idea why this happens and how to work around it? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a discussion with a fiends of mine (@dsotty, if you read this, I'm referring to you), I have found a solution.
The problem was in my `MemoryFileManager` which was only saving the bytecode of the last compiled class. Anytime I was trying to retrieve a class in a later time, I could only find the result of the last compilation. Drools needs to access the byte code of each class that enters its WM, therefore the `MemoryFileManager` was raising the `ClassNotFoundException` that was blocking the execution.

Now, the solution is as simple as replacing the `private MemoryJavaClassObject object;` inside it with a `private Map<String, MemoryJavaClassObject> objects;` where the bytecodes of all the classes can be successfully stored. So, anytime I try to compile something, I also store the bytecode in `objects` and when I try to find a class, I first have to look for an entry with the given `name` within `objects`. That's it!

The code for `MemoryFileManager` follows, for your convenience and ease of understanding:

```
public class MemoryFileManager extends ForwardingJavaFileManager<StandardJavaFileManager> {

    private Map<String, MemoryJavaClassObject> objects;

    public MemoryFileManager(StandardJavaFileManager manager) {
        super(manager);
        this.objects = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public ClassLoader getClassLoader(Location location) {
        return new SecureClassLoader() {
            @Override
            protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
                MemoryJavaClassObject object = objects.get(name);
                if (null == object)
                    throw new ClassNotFoundException("Class '" + name + "' not found.");
                byte[] b = object.getBytes();
                return super.defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public JavaFileObject getJavaFileForOutput(Location location, String name, Kind kind, FileObject sibling) throws IOException {
        MemoryJavaClassObject object = new MemoryJavaClassObject(name, kind);
        objects.put(name, object);
        return object;
    }

}
```

Further improvements are possible but are not included for brevity.